# Core Data - Will NSFetchedResultController automatically trace changes if I give NSPredicate and delegate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have a question about NSFetchedResultController updating problem.

As you may have already known, if I fetch all items and set the NSFetchedResultController's delegate, then if the data has been changed, the controller will catch the changes and auto update its objects.

But if I fetch items with NSPredicate, it does not catch any change nor its objects. Can someone tell me why?

Here is the codes with NSPredicate set.

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.globalContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:200]; 

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Department" ascending:YES selector:nil];

    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Department IN %@",departmentArray];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    self.resultsController = [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.globalContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"Department" cacheName:@"Root"] autorelease];
    self.resultsController.delegate = self;

    [self.resultsController performFetch:nil];
    [fetchRequest release];
```

In the code, I set the @"Department" as the sectionNameKeyPath, and I only need "Person" items from a number of Department (departmentArray), not all Departments.

If I remove the NSPredicate from the NSFetchRequest, then each time a person item with even a new department is inserted, the resultsController will know and trigger the delegate.

But If I keep the NSPredicate, the resultsController won't be able to know any change. For example:

My department array has the following names: @"Sales", @"Human Resources".

Initially, there is no persons from @"Sales" in the Core Data. I do a fetch,then only persons from @"Human Resources" are obtained.

Then a person from @"Sales" is inserted, I think the resultsController should automatically update, right? Because the new person with @"Sales" fits to the NSPredicate, right?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, I delete all caches before I do the fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate is not dynamic and does not respond to changes in the `departmentArray` after the predicate has been created. As far as the predicate is concerned, `departmentArray` only ever contains `Human Resources`. Further, the fetch request is likewise static and does not change so even if the predicate did change, the fetch request would not.

If you change the `departmentArray`, you need to generate a new fetch request for the fetched results controller.

Comment: Thanks, you are Core Data guru, you answered my another question of Core Data